# Output relocatable section data from linker script

Tags: linker, ld, binutils, linker-scripts

Using commands like `BYTE` or `LONG`, it is possible to [include explicit bytes of data in an output section](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Output-Section-Data.html#Output-Section-Data) from a linker script. The linked page also describes that those commands can be used to output the value of symbols.

I would have expected that if you perform partial linking (i.e., using the [`-r`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Options.html#index-relocatable-output-93) option of `ld`), relocation records would be emitted for the symbols that are outputted in this way. However, it seems that the linker just outputs the currently known value<sup>1</sup> of the symbol.

Here is a MWE to clarify what I mean.

`test.c`:

```
int foo = 1, bar = 2;
```

`test.ld`:

```
SECTIONS {
    .data : {
        *(.data)
        LONG(foo)
        LONG(bar)
    }
}
```

Then run the following:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$ ld -T test.ld -r -o test.elf test.o
$ readelf -r test.elf                

There are no relocations in this file.
$ readelf -x .data test.elf

Hex dump of section '.data':
  0x00000000 01000000 02000000 00000000 04000000 ................
```

As you can see, no relocations are created and the values that are outputted are the currently known values of `foo` and `bar`.

Could this be a bug? If not, is there any way to force the linker to output relocation records for symbols added to an output section?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not sure of this is the correct term. What I mean is the value that you see when you run `readelf -s` on the input object file.

Comment: Possibly because they are not referenced from anywhere. If you were to create the function `fubar` like `int fubar() { return foo+bar;}` I would expect that some from of relocation records would be produced. As I see it you wouldn't get relocation records with no references.
`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Well, they are referenced from the linker script but for some reason `ld` treats those references differently than the "normal" kind of references you mention.